# Marklogic excute Xquery code using java API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

Is there a way to execute xquery code, using marklogic java api.. Basically I want to get the size of a given file and in xquery I could just do the following

```
return xdmp:binary-size(fn:doc($uri)/binary())
```

Is there an easy way to do this using Java API ? or can we execute random xquery code using java API ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you have the [ServerEvaluationCall](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_70532) which enables both eval and invoke.  However, they require special privileges.  Eval is particularly dangerous because it opens up security risks when you send ad-hoc code from the client that might contain an injection attack.

Instead we recommend that you install and use a custom [resource extension](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_27702).

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for this:
Execute ad-hoc code on the server- with data mapped automatically to/from MarkLogic.
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_47102

Take it for a test drive - looks like it suits your needs.

You also have the robust resource service extension options:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_27702

My absolute favourite is this:
https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/java/resourceservices#id_84134
Full module execution on MarkLogic with injected variables - with data mapped automatically to/from MarkLogic

We use this option as follows:

- We have a wrapper function in Java.
- It executes a main module in MarkLogic which is also a wrapper function
- The markLogic function is a fancy invoker for any other modules.
  So, calling exec("a.b.c") on the java layer will actually execute function C in module B in directory A on the MarkLogic server -but the results are seamlessly available in the calling java code.

Its a bit more complex in real life(including security and per/post execution auditing), but certainly a pattern that can help you by keeping control over your xQuery/JS code and not allow injection of arbitrary code execution (because you execute only functions for which the connected user has rights to use).